# Find asset labels at runtime

Tags: unity, assets, asset-management

Unity allows me to add multiple labels to my assets in the editor (the little blue luggage tag in the corner of the inspector). I can use the [Asset Database](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html) to find all assets with a certain tag from the editor, but can I do the same thing at runtime? Maybe if the assets are in the resources folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t access the labels during runtime.

As you said methods like [AssetDatabase.GetLabels](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GetLabels.html) and [AssetDatabase.FindAssets](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html) are part of the namespace UnityEditor, which can’t be used in runtime.

**But what you could do** is: Write a editor script that export that all the labels information into a file and then in runtime read in that file, then you have a mapping of asset name to list of labels

```
// mapping labels by name
Dictionary<string, List<string>> labelsByName = ...;

// loaded texture 
Texture2D texture = ...;

// get labels of the texture
List<string> labels = labelsByName[texture.name];
```